# Conversion of fourth-order tensor multiplication from indices notation to matrix form

Tags: tensor-products, classical-mechanics, index-notation

Considering a 2D fourth-order tensor $C_{IJKL}$ which can be represented in Voigt notation as:
$$
C_{IJKL} = \begin{bmatrix}C_{1111}&C_{1122}&C_{1112}\\ C_{2211}&C_{2222}&C_{2212}\\ C_{1211}&C_{1222}&C_{1212}\end{bmatrix}
$$
and an asymmetric 2nd-order tensor $l_{mM}$ where:
$$
l_{mM}= \begin{bmatrix}
l_{11}&l_{12}\\
l_{21}&l_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We have two equations as below:
$$
Q_{mMnN} = C_{MJNL}l_{mJ}l_{nL}
$$
and
$$
Q_{mMnN} = C_{MNKL}\delta_{mn}(l_{kK}l_{kL}-1)
$$
How one can write above equations in matrix form? In general, what is happening in those equations?